# Remove unicode hex values using regex

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, hex

I need to remove several different hex values from a string of product descriptions.

Example:  "`Sale on CoolItem&#x2122; Watch`" OR "`Deal buster on RMKHoody&#8482; signed`"

```
&#x2122;  &#8482;
```

are just a few hex strings in this large database.

I need a reg exp to replace each with an empty string.

Result :  "`Sale on CoolItem Watch`" OR "`Deal buster on RMKHoody signed`"

What would be the reg exp to find the semi-col and select forward to the & and replace the entire selection?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION-WORKING CODE**

```
string s = "Sale on CoolItem&#x2122; Watch"
var cleanProductName = Regex.Replace(s, @"&#x?[^;]{2,4};", string.Empty);
cleanProductName = "Sale on CoolItem Watch"


string s = "Deal buster on RMKHoody&#8482; signed"
var cleanProductName = Regex.Replace(s, @"&#x?[^;]{2,4};", string.Empty);
cleanProductName = "Deal buster on RMKHoody signed"
```

You can also use

```
var cleanProductName = Regex.Replace(s, @"&[^;]{1,6};", string.Empty);
```

for more spec char such as ®  .  ™  . °

Comment: Do you have anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `&#x?[^;]{2,4};`, meaning: `&#` followed by zero or one `x` followed by 2 to 4 characters that are not `;`, followed by `;`.

Answer (score 0):

`\\&\\#x?\\d+\\;` could be a starting point.